# zf2 Additional Parameters to a PartialLoop

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a partial loop like this :

```
$this->size = 'small';
echo $this->partialLoop('item', $items);
```

I would like to get the variable 'size' inside my partial loop like that :

```
echo $this->view->size;
```

How to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Each item in your $items array should contain the size, then you can do $this->size from the partial template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use key/value pairs in your $items array.

For example, in addition to whatever else is in $items, you should set 'size' as a key and 'small' as a value. $items['size'] = 'small';

That will then get passed to the partial and you may reference it in the partial with $this->size

https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#partial-helper